# Error with strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a rare problem with variables between PHP and Javascript.

This is my example:

```
<?php $test = "123"; ?>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('.$test.');
 });
```

Works fine, but if i put $test = "hello"; doesn't works fine. Only works in JS when I put only numbers.

Comment: Are you sure it works with 123 ? Or does it just compile ?

Answer (score 3):

The php variable is a SERVER side variable. Javascript is accessing a variable on the CLIENT.  In order to get it into javascript you need to do something like:

```
<?php $test = "123"; ?>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('<?php echo($test); ?>');
});
```

That should do it!

---

**Alternate Approach**

The alternative is to set a variable in javascript so you have the value on the client. That looks like:

```
<?php $test = "123"; ?>
var $test = <?php echo($test); ?>;
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('.$test.');
});
```

The only nice part about this is that you can now use "$test" anywhere you need to without worrying about client versus server.

Comment: You forgot the `<script></script>` tags?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger Those tags can be wrapping this part of the PHP code.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger I assumed since they had a "$(document).ready" that this was already in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: In your Alternate Approach, maybe you want to use the `var` keyword. I'd hesitate to encourage a novice to begin javascript variable names with `$` but that's me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `echo`:

```
<?php $test = "hello"; ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('<?php echo $test; ?>');
});
</script>
```